# Evaluating real integral by complex contour method

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Please let me know where my mistake could be.

I've verified the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dt}{(t^2+1)(t^2+4)}$$
to be equal to $\frac{\pi}{6}$ with a computer math system.

However, I'm not getting the same answer when using theory of integration over contours in the complex plane.

Let $f(z):=\frac{1}{(z^2+1)(z^2+4)}$, $f(t):=\frac{1}{(t^2+1)(t^2+4)}$. The singularities of $f(z)$ are $\pm i, \pm 2i$. Let $R>2$ be the radius of the semicircle $C_R$ in the upper complex half-plane, so that $C_R$ encloses the two singularities $i$ and $2i$.

Thus we can write:

$$ \int_{-R}^R f(t)dt + \int_{C_R}f(z)dz=2\pi i (B_i + B_{2i})$$

where $B_k$ are the residues at the corresponding points.

One can determine that $(B_i + B_{2i}) = \frac{i}{4}$ and

$$ \int_{-R}^R f(t)dt = 2\pi i \frac{i}{4} + 0=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Please let me know where I'm mistaken.

Comment: I get $B_i=-\frac{i}{6}$ and $B_{2i}=\frac{i}{12}$, which would lead to the correct answer.

Comment: @carmichael561 You mean $\pm i, \pm 2i.$

Comment: @zhw.: There was a change in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)(z-2i)(z+2i)}$$ 
it follows that
$$ \mathrm{Res}_{z=i}f(z)=\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)f(z)=\frac{1}{(2i)(-i)(3i)}=\frac{1}{6i}=-\frac{i}{6}$$
and similarly
$$ \mathrm{Res}_{z=2i}f(z)=\frac{1}{i(3i)(4i)}=\frac{1}{-12i}=\frac{i}{12} $$
Therefore 
$$ 2\pi i\Big[\mathrm{Res}_{z=i}f(z)+\mathrm{Res}_{z=2i}f(z)\Big]=2\pi i\Big(-\frac{i}{6}+\frac{i}{12}\Big)=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Comment: As per one theorem, if $p(z)=1$, $q(z)=(z^2+1)(z^2+4)$, and $p(z_0)\ne 0$, $q(z_0)=0$, and $q'(z_0)\ne 0$, then $Res_{z=z_0}f(z) = \frac{1}{q'(z_0)}=\frac{1}{4mz_0^3+10mz_0}$ (where $m=1$ or $m=2$, depending on whether $B=i$ or $B=2i$). Hence, $B_k = \frac{1}{4mz_0^3 + 10mz_0}=\frac{1}{2mz_0(2z_0^2 + 5)}=\frac{1}{6mz_0}$. Hence, $B_i+B_{2i}=-\frac{i}{4}$. Please point out my mistake.

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{1}{4m^3z_0^3+10mz_0}$.